# Strange tooltip problems with winforms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, tooltip

I have an C# WinForm app (.NET Framework 4.8). I made ToolTips on (mostly) every button and it worked like a charm until few days ago. App and ToolTips work just fine on other PC's, but not mine. My PC runs Windows 11 x64 Version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.1992), just like unaffected PC's.Thank you in advance...

I have tried reinstalling .NET, but it didn't help.

Here is a method I'm running for ToolTips:

```
    public void InfoPop(string header, string tip, Button btn)
    {
        ToolTip btip = new ToolTip();
        btip.ToolTipTitle = header;
        btip.UseFading = true;
        btip.UseAnimation = true;
        btip.IsBalloon = true;
        btip.ShowAlways = true;
        btip.AutoPopDelay = 10000;
        btip.InitialDelay = 1000;
        btip.ReshowDelay = 500;
        btip.SetToolTip(btn, tip);
    }
```

Is it just "Windows magic" or anyone has the solution for it?

Comment: What's the issue on your PC? Not showing on right place? If yes, it may be related to your screen scaling.

Comment: They are not showing at all. Just stopped.

Comment: Do you recall any special things you did to your PC (installing an update, .NET, updating IDE, ...)? Also please try moving the button to somewhere else on the designer, move it back, then save the project and rebuild. Try editting the .cs code and rebuild as well.

Comment: Only windows regular updates where done, no errors occurred there. I have tried fiddling with buttons in all ways, no help. Also, same recompiled program works fine on other PC's...

Comment: I think the culprit is "June 13, 2023-KB5027119 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8.1 for Windows 11, version 22H2". My ToolTip problems started roughly same day...

Comment: You should probably not create a new Tooltip object for each button. Just create a single tooltip object and just call `SetTooltip` for each button.

Comment: JonasH thanx for the tip with optimization.

Comment: Found temporary solution to my problem. I just  removed "IsBalloon" property and it works on my PC.